# Can anyone assist me to read he details of the number 7 birth record of Howes?

Tags: 19th-century, birth-records, denmark, genealogical-societies, genealogy-community

[image]

Can anyone assist me to read he details of the number 7 birth record of Howes (Howse)?

[enter link description here](https://media.geni.com/p14/9d/c6/13/ac/534448644a787c72/02_original.jpg?hash=542c38f3aae6745fa37e1c4040bba58bdadaa1d92f29f7db47480ff6dafa354e.1697525999)

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I can read:

> No. 7
>
> 2 March 1855
>
> Sch.kl[?].mester
>
> William Howes og hustru Ellin Howse, 23 Aar? ved Jernbanen ved Korsber
>
> Bortvagit? efter H...s dag til England d. 17. Marts, uden har? .. .. döbt

Rough translation and interpretation:

- (Presumably) Born on 2 March 1855
- Parents William and Ellin Howse, they live (possibly temporarily) next to the railway towards Korsber
- They left for England on 17 March 1855, without having christened the child in the parish where the book is from